# get contet base on regex in to separate variables

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Is it possible to get every part of string base on regex? For instance I have:

```
#abc##!#[\s]+[\d]
```

I can target variables `#abc#` with regex `#.+?#`. However I would like to have both captured and the rest of string as well. So in the end I would like to have three variables:

```sh
#abc#
#!#
[\s]+[\d]
```

Is it possible using bash commands?

Comment: For this example, `grep -oE '#[^#]*#|[^#]*'` [should work](https://ideone.com/tCCGEg).

Comment: yes this is it! Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
 grep -oE '#[^#]*#|[^#]*' file
```

See an [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/tCCGEg)

**Pattern details**

- `#[^#]*#` - matches `#`, zero or more chars other than `#` and then a `#`
- `|` - or
- `[^#]*` - 0 or more chars other than `#`.

The `-o` parameter extracts matching substrings only and `-E` enables POSIX ERE engine (and `|` is an alternation operator here due to that).